# Calculate values within @HTML.TextBoxFor (MVC) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have four @Html.TextBoxFor as the code shows below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.money, "money", new { @class = "required numeric", id = "money", Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.money )})

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.money2, "money2", new { @class = "required numeric", id = "money2", Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.money2 )})

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.money3, "money3", new { @class = "required numeric", id = "money3", Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.money3 )})

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TotalMoney, "TotalMoney", new { @class = "required numeric", id = "TotalMoney", Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.TotalMoney )})
```

I previously used four

`<input type="text" id="money" onkeyup="sum();" name="money" value="@Model.money" />`

in order to add money, money 2 and money 3 together to produce a result in TotalMoney but it gives me a decimal problem and if I use TextBoxFor I don't get the decimal problem however I loose the calculation functionality.

JavaScript code I'm using is

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function sum() {
            var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('money').value;
            var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('money2').value;
            var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('money3').value;
            var result = parseFloat(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtSecondNumberValue) + parseFloat(txtThirdNumberValue);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('TotalMoney').value = result.toFixed(2);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And the JS works great with input but won't work at all with TextBoxFor, how can I adapt the JS into my TextBoxFor?

Comment: What is your issue exactly, Are you not able to get value in textbox which you given in "Value = String.Format("{0:C}", Model.money2 )})" ?

Comment: Not related, but you should be using the overload that accepts a format string, not trying to set the `value` attribute, and setting the `id` attribute is pointless (its already done for you) - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.money, "{0:C}", new { @class = "required numeric" })`. You javascript code would need to remove the currency symbol and thousands separator before doing the calculation, then add then back into the result.

Comment: If I use the Input element with JavaScript it works fine but the values have 4 decimal places (i.e. £15.1200, instead of £15.12). If I use @Html.TextBoxFor I get the 2 decimal places I want (£15.12) however the 3 money boxes loose their calculation functionality so when I enter values into them the don't automatically calculate the value into TotalMoney, where as the Input element does.

Comment: Stephen that worked perfect, thank you, big help!!. If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to adapt Stephen's answer to work as I needed it too. Stephen's answer as shown below worked great as it allowed my values to be displayed as for example £15.15, thus removing the 2 decimal places. However the only problem was I still lost the functionality of adding money, money 2 and money 3 together to automatically produce a total in TotalMoney.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.money, "{0:C}", new { @class = "required numeric" })
```

The slight change I made to Stephen's code is shown below. This removed the £ symbol however it also ensured my values retained 2 decimal places (i.e £13.12) and allowed my calculation functionality to work again.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.money, "{0:0.00}", new { @class = "required numeric", onkeyup = "sum()" })
```